# Multithreading performance test with Google Benchmark

Tags: benchmarking, google-benchmark

I am looking out for sample for testing multithread test using google benchmark library. In my case i have two functions - Reader() and writer() which are using common data structures protected by lock.

i have seen examples where one can run single function by multiple threads , but not where two different function getting called simultaneously in google benchmarking .